# Calculate CSS with jQuery: left: -100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create same Screenshot View logic as on Google Play.

The problem:

If you click on Screenshots on any Google Play app (e.g. [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca)), the picture enlarges and each click on the "Next Screenshot" changes `style="left: -100%"` > `style="left: -200%"` > `style="left: -300%"` inside of `<div class="expand-pages-container" style="left: -100%">...</div>`.

Clicking on Previous Button adds + `100%` to the `left:`: `style="left: -300%"` > `style="left: -200%"` > `style="left: -100%"`

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement all this with jQuery? Many Thanks

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far. directions to look in are get the current `left` value and add 100 or subtract 100 and assign the new value to the `left` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?
https://jsfiddle.net/Platonow/fo5ft3gj/12/

```
document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function() {
    move(100);
});

document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function() {
    move(-100);
});

var move = function(diffrencePercentage) {
  let images = document.getElementsByClassName("expand-pages-container")[0].getElementsByTagName("IMG");
  for(let i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.left = (parseInt(images[i].style.left) + diffrencePercentage) + "%";
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much, Damian! that was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

For how much info you provide in the question, this is the answer:

```
var hundred = parseInt($('div').css('left').replace(/px|\-/, '')));
// in this line we find how much 100% means in pixels.

var left = parseInt($('div').css('left').replace('px', '')));
// this is the actual position

$('.right-button').click(function () {
    left -= hundred;
    $('div').css('left', left + 'px');
});

$('.left-button').click(function () {
    left += hundred;
    $('div').css('left', left + 'px');
});
```